# How to abbreviate CSS path?

Tags: css

Is it possible to abreavite CSS path - if I know only the first element id name `#searchbar` and last inner component path class name `.autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title`. The path looks like:

```
#searchbar .some-uknown-to-me-path .autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title {
}
```

How can I replace `.some-uknown-to-me-path`? I'm trying to modify Firefox search bar (not url bar) popup. And I can not analyze popup with Ispector due to focus losing.

Comment: `#searchbar .ac-title` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply omit it:

```
#searchbar .autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title { }
```

Note that this will target any `.ac-title` element which has an ancestor `.autocomplete-richlistitem`, which itself has an ancestor `#searchbar`.

You can take this even further, and simply target `#searchbar .ac-title`, `.autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title`, or even just `.ac-title`. However, in doing so, you risk increasing the number of elements which will be matched by your selector. For example, the direct `.ac-title` selector will target any element with such a class, regardless of any of ancestors.

It's also worth noting that by *default* spaced CSS selectors will target *any* level of descendant. If you want to target an immediate child element, you can use the [child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). Unfortunately, you cannot do the inverse and target an element based on an ancestor (as there is no parent selector in CSS) -- you must work your way down.